# div's height isn't functioning when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I got a div that's set on `height: 100%` however i have a main content div with information in it, and it goes further than the side bar's div.

This is the error it shows, but i want the black bar - `side-bar` to be longer no matter what the size of the main content is. 
http://screencloud.net/v/rd9Y (image)

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    background: #e1e0de;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#notification-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #dbdbdb;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #dbdbdb;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #dbdbdb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}


#side-bar { 
    background: #232323;
    color: #656565;
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14%;
    z-index: 1;
    float:left;
}

.side-bar-container {
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: fixed;
}


#container {

}

#main-container {   
    margin: 60px 15px 0;
    float:left;
    width: 83%;
}

.user-stats-container {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}   

#main-content-box {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 0 auto 28px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #656565;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #656565;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #656565;
    padding: 15px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="notification-bar">
                notification bar Swag
            </div>

            <div id="container">

                <div id="side-bar">
                    <div class="side-bar-container">
                        side bar swag
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="main-container">

                    <div class="user-stats-container ">

                        user stats swag 

                    </div>

                    <div id="main-content-box">

                        Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>Main content swag<br><br><br><br><br><br>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

I have the `side-bar` set to a height of 100%, but it doesn't seem like it wants to work. Any ideas?

Comment: [Read up on faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns), or if older browsers are of no concern - consider `display:table-cell` and/or flexboxes.

Comment: The first thing to work on, for me, is why don't your borders show? Also, why are you using z-index? Then, how come your "swag" text doesn't render in these divs     <div class="side-bar-container">
                        side bar swag
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="main-container">

                    <div class="user-stats-container ">

                        user stats swag 

                    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `#container` add this css

```
float: left;
```

Because the side bar and main container are using `float` so you need the wrapper to have the `float` thing